# How do I run a meta tag using php?

Tags: php, if-statement, meta-tags, meta

I want to run this line of code in a php if statement.How would I do this?

```
 if (mail("m@me.com",$subject,$ipmessage,$header) ==1){
    echo "Thank You Your Message Has Been Sent!";
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=index.php">
}
```

Comment: why not ur using php header() function ??   if (mail("m@me.com",$subject,$ipmessage,$header) ==1){
    echo "Thank You Your Message Has Been Sent!"; ?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=index.php">
<?php } ?>

Comment: i updated and aded the link for header function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (mail("m@me.com",$subject,$ipmessage,$header)){
    echo "Thank You Your Message Has Been Sent!";
  ?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=index.php">
 <?php
  }
?>
```

For **HEADER** in php --

[HEADER](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

**FINAL EDIT** -

```
 if (mail("m@me.com",$subject,$ipmessage,$header)){
    echo "Thank You Your Message Has Been Sent!";
    header("Refresh: 3;index.php");
  }
```

Comment: Would that only run when that if statement is true?

Comment: @MaxGee Is it not in the if block?

Comment: @swapnesh Can you use HEADER to redirect after a certain number of seconds?

Comment: @Daedalus It is but I wasn't sure if that still applied if php was ended.

Comment: @MaxGee You can't have PHP do something after the page has loaded, you need something on the client side to request whatever gets triggered by the PHP

Comment: @swapnesh Oh yeah I forgot that it was server side.But the meta tag will work fine for what i am needing thanks for all the help!

Comment: although im not sure but have a try with this - header("Refresh: 2;index.php");

Comment: @MaxGee yeah its working at my end tested :) let me update my answer

Comment: @swapnesh Iam getting a error when I tried it.Here is the error.  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: @MaxGee its a warning .. add ob_start() at the starting of your file

Comment: @swapnesh At the very start or at the start of the if statement?

Comment: @MaxGee at the very start and lemme know if its working or not

Comment: @swapnesh I clicked the check!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with header redirect after certain time interval.

```
<?php 
ob_start();

if (mail("m@me.com",$subject,$ipmessage,$header)){

    echo "Thank You Your Message Has Been Sent! ";
    header("Refresh: 10; url=index.php"); //You will be redirect in 10 seconds
  }


ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: I got this error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: That is interfering with a else statement that I have after that.It is saying unexpected else.

Comment: I found a way to make it work.Thank you for all of your help.